# Display a "YTD" automatically for the current month with a worksheet level VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

can I have some ideas on how to construct this event level VBA on a worksheet level?

If current month matches the month on the cell 4 rows below ("BC5") then put "YTD" with black background in this cell ("BC1") and the previous cells in the row for the previous months.

For example, we are in June already so "YTD" should be already visible in the top row.

See image below.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the month headers in what looks like row 3 or 4 are real dates, you can use a formula like this in cell AX1 and copy to the right

```
=IF(TODAY()>AX4,"YTD","")
```

Then add conditional formatting to highlight cells that are equal to "YTD" and change the format to your liking.

[image]

Comment: They are real dates (1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, etc.). Thank you for the solution. I think I will stick with your formula solution than writing one in VBA.

Comment: It does not work for July - December when I just drag the formula? Formula for July (BD1) is =IF(TODAY() >= BD$5, "YTD", ""). How come? Sorry, my Calculation Options is set to Manual. Please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is also a LYTD (Last Year To Date), I have used the following solution:

=IF(MONTH(TODAY()) >= MONTH(AQ5), "LYTD", "")

Thank you Teylyn for the original solution.